# Prevent loading of Ajax content directly

Tags: html, ajax

My website loads some tabs using `AJAX`.  The content of the tab pages are PHP files.

I noticed that some users are going directly to the tab content pages (which they should not).

1. Is there a way to prevent users from directly accessing those pages?  (Perhaps redirect them to a parent page if they load directly)?
2. Is there a way to prevent bots from offering these `TAB` pages directly? I tried adding the following into the `TAB` pages, but not sure if that's enough:

   ```
   <link href="http://www.example.com/parent/index.php" rel="canonical">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to block direct access.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== "http://www.example.com/parent/index.php") {
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/parent/index.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```